How to create a vector of files in R
I tried to open several files to write debug information to them. For easy access I want to store their handles in a vector. Unfortunately it appears R does not create new file handles but uses one handle multiple times.
This is the source code:
> Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")
> f<-NULL
> for(i in 1:10)
+ {
+     fn<-paste("deb/name",i,sep="_")
+     af<-file(fn,"w")
+     cat(file=af,"opened file",i,"\n")
+     cat("opened file",i,fn,"\n")
+     f<-c(f,af)
+     showConnections(all=T)
+ }

print(f)
for(i in 1:10)
{
    cat(file=f[i],"wrote to file",i,"\n")
}


which yields the following output:
opened file 1 deb/name_1 
opened file 2 deb/name_2 
opened file 3 deb/name_3 
opened file 4 deb/name_4 
opened file 5 deb/name_5 
opened file 6 deb/name_6 
opened file 7 deb/name_7 
opened file 8 deb/name_8 
opened file 9 deb/name_9 
opened file 10 deb/name_10 
Warning messages:
1: In .Internal(gc(verbose, reset, full)) :
  closing unused connection 3 (deb/name_1)
2: In .Internal(gc(verbose, reset, full)) :
  closing unused connection 4 (deb/name_2)
3: In .Internal(gc(verbose, reset, full)) :
  closing unused connection 3 (deb/name_3)
4: In .Internal(gc(verbose, reset, full)) :
  closing unused connection 4 (deb/name_4)
5: In .Internal(gc(verbose, reset, full)) :
  closing unused connection 3 (deb/name_5)
6: In .Internal(gc(verbose, reset, full)) :
  closing unused connection 4 (deb/name_6)
7: In .Internal(gc(verbose, reset, full)) :
  closing unused connection 3 (deb/name_7)
8: In .Internal(gc(verbose, reset, full)) :
  closing unused connection 4 (deb/name_8)
9: In .Internal(gc(verbose, reset, full)) :
  closing unused connection 3 (deb/name_9)
> print(f)
 [1] 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4
> for(i in 1:10)
+ {
+     cat(file=f[i],"wrote to file",i,"\n")
+ }
Error in cat(file = f[i], "wrote to file", i, "\n") : invalid connection
Execution halted

It seems R at some point declares the files as unused an closes the connection.
I expected to have the message "opened file" and "wrote to file" in each file in the directory deb

You can't put connections into a vector. You need to store them in a list. The connections are closed because you assign a different connection to af and the old connection isn't bound to any symbol anymore.
Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")

f <- list()
# for long lists use f <- vector(mode = "list", length = 10L)

for (i in 1:10) {
  fn <- paste("name",i,sep="_")
  f[[i]] <- file(fn,"w")
  cat(file=af,"opened file",i,"\n")
  cat("opened file",i,fn,"\n")
}

showConnections(all=T)
#   description class      mode text   isopen   can read can write
#0  "stdin"     "terminal" "r"  "text" "opened" "yes"    "no"     
#1  "stdout"    "terminal" "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
#2  "stderr"    "terminal" "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
#3  "name_1"    "file"     "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
#4  "name_1"    "file"     "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
#5  "name_2"    "file"     "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
#6  "name_3"    "file"     "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
#7  "name_4"    "file"     "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
#8  "name_5"    "file"     "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
#9  "name_6"    "file"     "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
#10 "name_7"    "file"     "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
#11 "name_8"    "file"     "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
#12 "name_9"    "file"     "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"    
#13 "name_10"   "file"     "w"  "text" "opened" "no"     "yes"  

for (i in 1:10) close(f[[i]])

You might want to replace the first for loop with a lapply loop for convenience:
f <- lapply(1:10, \(i) file(paste("name",i,sep="_"),"w"))

PS: It is bad practice to grow a vector in a loop. Avoid that and preallocate atomic vectors. You don't need to care about that so much with lists because a list is just a vector of pointers to the list elements internally and usually list lengths are not huge.

In principle the exact same advice applies for growing vectors and growing lists: both are contiguous storage that needs to be reallocated and copied when resizing them. For small-ish sequences (up to a few thousand elements) it doesn’t matter for either.

@KonradRudolph And the JIT compiler might optimize it away. But it's still advisable to use best practice. And huge lists tend to be rare.

Yes, I agree that it’s generally a good idea to follow best practices. My comment was more about the fact that vectors and lists are the same in this regard.

In theory yes, but in practice the issue is rarely a problem with common list sizes.
